# ItemsControl Validation style not updating when adding/removing items

Tags: c#, wpf, observablecollection, itemscontrol, idataerrorinfo

I have an `ItemsControl` that is bound to an `ObservableCollection`. This collection has a validation rule (using `IDataErrorInfo`) that basically says 'If there is a 'Quote' in this list, then there has to be a 'Customer' as well.

I can see that the validation rule is working as expected as I have a button bound to a command that can't execute if there are errors. However, the `ItemsControl` is not visually updating with the error style.

This error style does work. I'm using it on a number of other controls (mainly `TextBox` and `ComboBox`) and it does show on the `ItemsControl` if the bound collection is set to a new collection. It is purely on adding and removing that the error style does not update.

```
<ItemsControl Margin="5" ItemsSource="{e:Binding Path=CurrentBooking.Regardings}" Background="Transparent">
    <!-- Items Panel and ItemTemplate Stuff -->
</ItemsControl>
```

`e:Binding` is a custom `Binding` that, amongst other things, sets the 3 ValidatesOn... properties to true. `CurrentBooking.Regardings` is the `ObservableCollection`

This is the empty user control. The plus icon is used to add items to the collection.

[image: Initial state of the ItemsControl]

This should have the error style applied as there is a quote and no customer. The button mentioned above is disabled, showing that there is an error.
[image: ItemsControl with Quote]

If I instead create a new collection with the added item, it does apply the style. However, I don't particularly want to create a new collection every time an item is added or removed.
[image: ItemsControl With working error template]

Code for error style:

```
<Style x:Key="ErrorStyle" TargetType="FrameworkElement">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
            <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
             Path=(Validation.Errors).CurrentItem.ErrorContent}"/>
        </Trigger>
        <!--Clear Template if false-->
        <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false">
            <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style TargetType="ItemsControl" BasedOn="{StaticResource ErrorStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
</Style>
```

Comment: While this isn't a solution, It could avoid the problem (if possible). Why not prompt the user to input quote AND user at the same time (through like a popup window)?

Comment: This is going to happen at some point (adding a quote will also add the customer attached to the quote) but then the user could then just remove the customer from the collection and I wouldn't want to prevent this as they may want to change it to a different customer.